# Computing entropy for data compression

Tags: compression, entropy

I am a little confused about how they calculate "average number of bits per symbol". Is this calculated by taking the probability of each character and multiplying it by the lg(1/probability) like regular entropy, or some other way?

Also, if this is true, how do they know for sure what the average occurrence of a letter is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really shouldn't answer this because I don't know much about compression, but I can say:

- How is "bits per symbol" defined?

You are correct; it's regular entropy defined as `-Σp·log(p)`. Note that this isn't actually *frequency of character* but *frequency of message*. ie, the following set of messages

```
{ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz }
```

Looks great analyzed letter-by-letter, but has an entropy of 0.

- How can you know what the average occurrence of a letter is?

It is theoretically impossible to know for sure, unless you know the exact process by which the message is generated. You have to use some heuristic. Like taking a large sample and counting, or looking for patterns that you know are signs of redundancy. Such as english text, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response :-) sorry if this is a stupid question buy does the message have an entropy of 0?

Comment: @rubixbuc The set of messages has an entropy of zero because there's only 1 message in it.